# If the difference of scores is normally distributed, the sample distributions don't matter in a paired t-test, right?

Tags: r, t-test, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a very straight-forward question:
***If the difference of scores is normally distributed, the sample distributions don't matter in a paired t-test, right?***
Therefore, If the samples are not normally-distributed, but their differences are (Scores 2 - Scores 1), then it's ok to run the parametric test?

I've seen some related questions, but not this specifically one ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/can-i-use-a-paired-t-test-when-the-samples-are-normally-distributed-but-their-di) [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Paired_t-test_and_normality_test_question) , for example).

Comment: Just to add a small comment. Even if the differences are not normal (although it is an assumption), the paired t-test often performs well anyway.

Comment: Correct, though you can't know that the differences *are* normal (not that this is important).

Comment: @Glen_b exactly, which is why the robustness of the paired t-test to non-normality is beneficial (and makes it useful).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct. A paired *t*-test is conducted on the differences of the paired scores. It doesn't look at the individual scores in any way.

A paired *t*-test is precisely the same as a one-sample *t*-test on the differences of the pairs.

Consider the following observations, *A* and *B*.  While the distributions of each are skewed, the differences are relatively symmetric and bell-shaped in distribution.

The results of the paired *t*-test and one-sample *t*-test are the same.

*A = (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)*

*B = (0.98, 2.10, 3.84, 4.11, 3.02, 3.01, 5.67, 5.07, 6.20, 5.67, 6.77, 7.61,
6.15, 9.32, 8.41, 7.71, 8.64, 8.49, 8.15, 9.00, 8.80, 7.85, 8.90)*

In R:

```
A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)

B = c(0.98, 2.10, 3.84, 4.11, 3.02, 3.01, 5.67, 5.07, 6.20, 5.67, 6.77, 7.61,
      6.15, 9.32, 8.41, 7.71, 8.64, 8.49, 8.15, 9.00, 8.80, 7.85, 8.90)

hist(A)

hist(B)

Difference = A - B

hist(Difference)

t.test(A, B, paired=TRUE)

t.test(Difference)

   ### Paired t-test
   ### t = -3.3339, df = 22, p-value = 0.00301
   ###
   ### One Sample t-test
   ### t = -3.3339, df = 22, p-value = 0.00301
```

Comment: thank you very much! This answer was really helpful! 